# How to use numbers (cite, cross-ref) from another .tex in Beamer?

Tags: beamer, cross-referencing, numbering, citing, books

I'm writing a thesis in srcbook while creating the presentation in beamer.

Can I make the beamer to use the same numbers such as a citation and cross-reference to sections, figures, tables, etc. that are numbered in the thesis?

For example, a figure is numbered as "Fig. 2" in my thesis. Since I skip about Fig. 1 in the presentation, I omit the figure 1 from the presentation. But then the figure 2 will be Fig. 1 on beamer.

I wish to have the same numbering to avoid confusion in professors.

Comment: You can use the [`xr` package](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/xr)

Comment: @Pengin Does above comment solve your problem?